# Replace or push to array in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, algorithm

I have an array of orders and when i recieve a message from my websocket with a new placement order or a modified order i want to check against my orders array, if there is an exisitng order with the websocket message replace the object in the array with the websocket message, else push it to the array.

example:

```
const orderArr = [
{
id: 1,
item: 'apple',
price: 20
},
{
id: 2,
item: 'mango',
price: 10
},
{
id: 3,
item: 'cucumber',
price: 300
}
]

const webSocketOrder = {
id: 1,
item: 'apple',
price: 40
}

// what should happen to the order array
[
{
id: 1,
item: 'apple',
price: 40
},
{
id: 2,
item: 'mango',
price: 10
},
{
id: 3,
item: 'cucumber',
price: 300
}
]
```

but if the `webSocketOrder` is a new item with a new id it should be added as a new item in the `orderArr`

what i have done

```
const foundOrder = orderArr.find(
          (x) => x.id === webSocketOrder.id
        );
        if (foundOrder) {
          orderArr.map((ord) =>
            ord.id === webSocketOrder.id 
              ? webSocketOrder
              : ord
          );
        } else {
          orderArr.unshift(webSocketOrder);
        }
```

this doesnt work for some reason, please can someone help?

Comment: There is no typescript anywhere in your code...

Comment: my mistake, i removed those bits

Comment: Read about array operations in detail. Your find, map and unshift usage is wrong

Comment: Why are you calling array like a function: `orderArr( (x) => ..)`

Comment: sorry thats meant to be orderArr.find

Comment: Use `findIndex` instead: `const i = orderArr.findIndex(x => x.id === webSocketOrder.id)`. And then replace the item at that index `orderArr[i] = webSocketOrder`

Comment: don’t use Array, use a more appropriate data structure like Map

Answer (score 2):

You can use find()/findIndex() to loop over the array just once.

```js
 const index = orderArr.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === webSocketOrder.id);

    if (index === -1) {
        orderArr.push(webSocketOrder);
    } else {
        orderArr[index] = webSocketOrder;
    }
```

Comment: Great stuff. Saved my day!

Answer (score 0):

If you're replacing the order in place (not treating the array as immutable) you can use `splice`

```
const index = orderArr.findIndex((obj) => obj.id === webSocketOrder.id);

orderArr.splice(index > -1 ? index : orderArr.length, index > -1 ? 1 : 0, webSocketOrder);
```